# read_csv() pandas after update to 1.2.4

Tags: python, pandas

After updating pandas to the newest version (1.2.4), I am getting an error upon trying to read in a csv-file. Code did not change.

`df = pd.read_csv('path_to_file', index_col=0, header=0)`

I get the following error:

`AttributeError: 'Index' object has no attribute '_ndarray_values'`.

When I run `df = pd.read_csv('path_to_file', header=0)`, it works fine.

Any ideas on how to resolve this?

Comment: Give minimum reproducible example

Comment: It's reading in a csv-file...

Comment: @Archie Does it happen for all files or is it specific to that file? What happens when you remove `index_col=0`? Can you try to reproduce it with a small CSV file (a few columns and a few rows)?

Comment: Yeah, it's all files. That's why I'm thinking it's due to the update (a mix-up in the dependencies?), but no clue on the specifics... When I leave out `index_col = 0` it's fine.

Comment: Downgraded pandas to previous version fixed it for now.